# How to stop fan gate / like gate from redirecting to wall when clicking "Like"

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-like

I've created a Facebook fan page that works as a fan gate / like gate.  When the user clicks the "Like" button the page redirects to the wall.  I want to override this behavior and have the page redirect back to the Liked version of the fan gate.  The app is an iFrame page tab app using the PHP signed request to determine liked/notliked status.

An example of this is http://www.facebook.com/1800flowers
When you like the page, it redirects you to http://www.facebook.com/1800flowers?sk=app_116748578401618

So my search-fu found a piece of JavaScript that was supposed to fix this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top != self) top.window.location = 'linkgoeshere';
</script>
```

I've tried placing this block of JavaScript in both the have liked and have not liked sections of the page.  Either way it creates a redirect loop where the page just continually refreshes.

If this code is the answer, where should it be located, and what should "linkgoeshere" be replaced with?  There is a possibility I've been using the wrong link.

If this isn't the answer, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having this problem for the past few days, but today I found the solution. You were right with your suspicions that this is caused by the new recommend dialog box on pages. This box only appears on pages for PLACES. If you have a address assigned to your page then remove it and your fangate will reload in the window when liked and not redirect to the wallpage.

Comment: Looks like this will have to be my accepted answer.  I don't terribly want to do that, but it looks like the only way.  Thank you for confirming my suspicions.  I can't believe that I can't find more people that are asking about this. :/

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug on facebook right now, described here - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/110015112440103

It'd be great to have an interim fix but since the code for the Like button is outside of what's accessible to the page tab, I'm having trouble imaging what a solution might look like, short of removing the address from your page to make it not a "place", which seem to be the only pages affected.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need any JavaScript.

Makes sure you set the "Default Landing Tab" to be your fan gate in the "Manage Permissions" section of the page Admin.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike.  I have the Default Landing Tab set to the fan gate.  It works when they land on the page if they haven't liked it.  It is after they like it that the redirect happens.

Comment: Is the app in sandbox mode? After the like is clicked, it should just reload the page with whatever app you were on.

Comment: The app is not in sandbox mode.  There is the new recommend thing that pops up when the like button is clicked though.  Is it possible that this is causing the error?  Is there maybe a way to disable that?

Comment: I wish I could help you more. The [Best Of College Football app](https://www.facebook.com/bestofcollegefootball?sk=app_245265378850982) has similar fan gate functionality. If you like that page (while you are on the app), does it redirect you to the wall? I can guarantee there is no fancy redirect JS or anything of that nature on that app.

Comment: Yeah, I've been able to find a handful of pages that all work properly.  I honestly think that it has to do with the "Recommend" button that comes up whenever you click the "Like".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I use. Also, be sure as marked above to set the default landing tab. You will need to download the latest facebook sdk for php, and replace the lines for your app ID, app secret, and the path to your fanpage int he $loginNextPage below.

Notice that there are two places where you can add your own HTML or an include of the page content that should be served for the appropriate audiences.

Also, returning users who liked you pages always get the wall by default, no matter what you set as the default tab. So if they leave and come back, they will get the wall.

```
 <?php

    require 'facebook.php';                

    $app_id = "YOUR APP ID";
    $app_secret = "YOUR APP SECRET";
    $loginNextPage = 'YOUR FAN PAGE URL'.'?sk=app_'.$app_id;

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => $app_id,
            'secret' => $app_secret,
            'cookie' => true
    ));



    $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

    $page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
    $like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];


    if ($like_status) {
        // FOR FANS
        $session = $facebook->getSession();
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                array(
                'canvas'    => 1,
                'fbconnect' => 0,
                'next' => $loginNextPage,
                'req_perms' => 'publish_stream,photo_upload,user_photos,user_photo_video_tags'          
                )
        );

        $fbme = null;

        if (!$session) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";    
            exit;   
        }
        else {

            try {
                $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
                $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
                $user = $facebook->getUser();

                $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$user;
                $info = file_get_contents($url);
                $info = json_decode($info); 
                $vars = "id=$user&first_name=$info->first_name&last_name=$info->last_name&access_token=$access_token&pathToServer=$pathToServer&appName=$appName";

            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
                exit;
            }


    // Begin Like Gated Content.        
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">   
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>You Have Liked The Page</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?
        }   
    }
    else {
        // FOR NON FANS
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">   
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
      </head>
      <body>
      <h1>Click Like To View Content</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The way it is built currently doesn't require all of the authorization information.  Using the provided code I get the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::getSession().  The method that I'm using to control the has liked or not is in the most popular answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703678/how-to-determine-if-facebook-user-likes-a-certain-page)